# Accessing data from an entire AcitveAdmin filtered collection

Tags: activeadmin

Trying to figure this problem out and not having much luck. Right now, I am using ActiveAdmin and Im trying to display at the top of my dashboard page, the total number of books sold in my current collection. Just a little background; my database entries are Orders, which have many columns, one of which being number_books. I have found I can tally the number_books for the first page of the paginated sorted collection, and I have found a way to tally ALL number_books for every instance of Order in the database, what I haven't been able to do is to tally for the entire current filtered collection, as using the following results in only the sum  total from the first page of the paginated collection.

```
"Total Books on page: #{collection.pluck(:number_books).reduce(:+)}"
```

Does anyone know of a way to access the entire filtered collection? The person I am working on this for does not want to have to scroll through each page and manually tally the number of books from each page if they don't have to because there could be 20, 30, or 40 pages of records which have been sorted in the current collection by whatever they are trying to sort the Orders for.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
"Total Books on page: #{controller.send(:find_collection, except: :pagination).sum(&:number_books)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem.

```
Order.ransack(params[:q]).result.map{|order| order.number_books}.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: Order.ransack(params[:q]).result.sum(&:number_books}